# Visibility of a Django formview in templates

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I've followed the tutorial here to implement a basic search function: https://learndjango.com/tutorials/django-search-tutorial

I'd like to extend that tutorial by making the search function visible on the results page, allowing for repeated search. However, when I do this I can't get the search form to show up on the search results page. The search button shows up, but not the field to provide input.

Relevant code:

home.html:

```
<div name="searchform">
    <form action="{% url 'search_results' %}" method="get">
        {{ form }}
        <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
</div>
{% block content %}

{% endblock %}
```

search_results.html:

```
{% extends home.html}
{% block content %}
<h1>Search Results</h1>

<ul>
  {% for city in object_list %}
    <li>
      {{ city.name }}, {{ city.state }}
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

Views.py:

```
from django.db.models import Q
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, ListView, FormView

from .models import City



class HomePageView(FormView):
    template_name = 'home.html'
    form_class = SearchForm

class SearchResultsView(ListView):
    model = City
    template_name = 'search_results.html'
    
    def get_queryset(self): 
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        object_list = City.objects.filter(
            Q(name__icontains=query) | Q(state__icontains=query)
        )
        return object_list
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import HomePageView, SearchResultsView

urlpatterns = [
    path('search/', SearchResultsView.as_view(), name='search_results'),
    path('', HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),
]
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    q = forms.CharField(label='', max_length=50, 
                    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Search Here'})             
                    )
```

Any advice on how I might troubleshoot this sort of issue (or if I'm blatantly doing something un-django-y) would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using ListView which is a *Generic display view*.
You need to use `get` method, then you can pass the form to make the search again and stay on the same page.

```
class SearchResultsView(View):

    template_name = 'search_results.html'
    form_class = SearchForm

    def get(self, request):
        form = self.form_class()
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        context = {}
        context['form'] = form
        context['cities'] = City.objects.filter(
            Q(name__icontains=query) | Q(state__icontains=query)
        )
        return render(self.request, self.template_name, context)
```

You can achieve the same result with **ListView** but is better if you use other based view class.

You can check the doc. [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/)

Comment: this + some modifications to my template did it, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```py
class HomePageView(FormView):
    template_name = 'home.html'
    form_class = SearchForm      # This line!
```

Remember to also apply the `form_class` attribute to `SearchResultsView`, otherwise, no forms will be interpreted. The submit button only shows up because it's not a part of the rendered form.